# How to get total sum of all values of a data frame using awk

Tags: shell, awk

Suppose I have a data frame like:

```
A,B,C,D
2,1,1,1
2,3,1,4
```

I want to get the total sum of the data frame, meaning that just a total value as an output.
So for the given example, the output should be `15`

I tried this but it gives sum for each column:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {sum=0; OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=$i } END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Because you only want to output one number, `OFS=","` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} FNR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i}} END{print sum}'  Input_file
```

***What's not working in OP's approach:*** OP's logic is correct but we don't want to use array here, we need a simple variable which has all sum in it then in `END` block of code we need to print it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach :-)

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{s=s FS$0}END{gsub(FS,"+",s);print "0"s}' file|bc
```

got `15`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with GNU awk. This transforms the file to one column and sums it up.

```
awk '{s+=$0} END{print s}' RS='[,\n]' file
```

Output:

```
15
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)